# Laravel ->with() can't be shown in blade (Undefined property)

Tags: arrays, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pass an article from my controller to my view using laravel 5.3
if I just use {{ $selectedArticle }} I get the full output :

```
[{"id":5,"title":"Up up and awayy",
  "link":"www.google.be",
  "points":0,
  "userID":1,
  "isDeleted":"FALSE",
  "created_at":"2017-01-25 23:53:19",
  "updated_at":"2017-01-25 23:53:56"
}]
```

But when I try using `$selectedArticle->id` I get the following error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$id

How can I call on the properties of the article separatly? (call the id, title,... )

My controller code:

```
public function index($id)
{

    $comments = DB::table('comments')->orderBy('id')->where(['artikelID' => $id, 'isDeleted' => 'FALSE'])->get();
    $article = DB::table('articles')->orderBy('id')->where(['id'=> $id])->get();
    return view('comments.comments')
        ->with('storedComments', $comments)
        ->with('artikelid',$id)
        ->with('selectedArticle', $article);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable you're passing to the view is an array and to display the value you should loop through the array like this.

```
@foreach($selectedArticle as $article)

    {{ $article->id }}

@endforeach
```

Or if you'd like to select only one object using `first()` function to get the first row, like this:

```
$article = DB::table('articles')->orderBy('id')->where(['id'=> $id])->first();
```